# Does income from selling long term stocks fall under regular income tax bracket or capital income tax bracket?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax

If both brackets are the same, please let me know. I plan to sell some of my long term stocks and want to make an informed decision.

My understanding of regular income tax is that it includes salary, bonus and RSUs. Capital gains is about assets sold in long/short term. Please correct me if I am wrong.

For the tax brackets, I am referring to this article - https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/taxes/capital-gains-tax-rates

Comment: Tax questions must have a country tag. What country are you in. Also, are you talking about Federal taxes or state/local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about US Federal Income tax you will pay the long term capital gain rate for any stocks you held more than a year. The taxed amount will be the proceeds minus the total cost of purchasing them.

Capital gains are basically gains on any investment asset that you earned a profit from appreciation in value, as opposed to earned income that you received for selling your labor.

Comment: Same for Australia. 1/2 CGT if held over 1 year

Comment: Thank you, @JohnFx. Yes, its about US Federal Income tax. Suppose the income from salary is $50k (just an example :) and the proceeds from long term stock sell minus total cost of purchasing stock is another $50k, so what falls under the regular income bracket and what falls under the capital tax income bracket?

Comment: The first $50k falls under earned income, and the $50k gain in your investments is capital tax. As you might expect. It is as simple as that.